# Contar días hábiles dado 2 fechas

Tags: java, android, calendar

Tengo una función que no se cae, pero se demora mucho y me muestra muchos errores (que según yo, no lo son).

> Must be one of: Calendar.SUNDAY, Calendar.MONDAY, Calendar.TUESDAY,
>   Calendar.WEDNESDAY, Calendar.THURSDAY, Calendar.FRIDAY,
>   Calendar.SATURDAY

Estas lineas me marca con error:

```
Calendar.JANUARY, Calendar.MAY, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, Calendar.DECEMBER.   
cal2.get(Calendar.DATE)==1, cal2.get(Calendar.DATE)==18, cal2.get(Calendar.DATE)==19, cal2.get(Calendar.DATE)==25.
```

Adjunto Captura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
// calcula los dias que faltan para que venza el ticket
public Integer getDiasLaborales () {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        Date fechaActual = sdf.parse(sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
        Date fechaTermino = sdf.parse(fecha_termino);

        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.setTime(fechaTermino);
        cal2.setTime(fechaActual);
        float dias = (float)(fechaTermino.getTime() - fechaActual.getTime()) / 86400000;  // 1 dia = 1000*60*60*24*1

        float numberOfDays = Math.abs(dias) - Math.abs((int) dias) - 1;  // valor absoluto
        if(dias < 0) {
            while (cal1.before(cal2)) {
                if ((cal1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY) // Los Domingos
                    &&!(((cal1.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1) &&(cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.JANUARY))  // Año Nuevo
                    &&((cal1.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1) &&(cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.MAY)  // Día Nacional del Trabajo
                    &&((cal1.get(Calendar.DATE) == 18) &&(cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.SEPTEMBER))  // Independencia Nacional
                    &&((cal1.get(Calendar.DATE) == 19) && (cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.SEPTEMBER))  // Día de las Glorias del Ejército
                    &&((cal1.get(Calendar.DATE) == 25) &&(cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.DECEMBER))  // Navidad
                    )){
                        numberOfDays++;
                    }
                    cal1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
                }
                numberOfDays = numberOfDays * -1;
            } else {
                while (cal2.before(cal1)) {
                    if ((cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY)  // Los Domingos
                        && !(((cal2.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1) &&(cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.JANUARY))  // Año Nuevo
                        && ((cal2.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1) && (cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.MAY))  // Día Nacional del Trabajo
                        && ((cal2.get(Calendar.DATE) == 18) && (cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.SEPTEMBER))  // Independencia Nacional
                        && ((cal2.get(Calendar.DATE) == 19) && (cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.SEPTEMBER))  // Día de las Glorias del Ejército
                        && ((cal2.get(Calendar.DATE) == 25) && (cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH) == Calendar.DECEMBER))  // Navidad
                        )){
                            numberOfDays++;
                    }
                    cal2.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
                }
            }
            //Log.d(TAG, String.format("%s : %.2f ---> %.2f", sdf.format(fechaTermino), dias, numberOfDays));
            //Log.d(TAG, dias+" ---> "+numberOfDays+"\n\n");
            return numberOfDays > 0 ? (int)Math.ceil(numberOfDays) : (int)Math.floor(numberOfDays); //ceil: redondea arriba cualquier decimal y floor: quita el decimal y lo aproxima para abajo
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

¿A que se debe este error y como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: es extraño, copie tu codigo exactamente, no me retorna ningun error, que fechas estas ocupando?

Comment: estoy usando las mismas que comente. deja subir una captura

Comment: acabo de reemplazar los errores por "Calendar.SUNDAY" y me marca como correcto, pero no tiene sentido! :(

Comment: copia y pega el codigo que te deje (despues lo voy a borrar si, asi que copialo y pegalo)

Comment: @sioesi era el mismo código :S

Comment: si, es que vi que te faltaba un parentesis en el primer while, pero vi en la foto que subiste que si esta

Comment: pudiste solucionarlo? tengo que hacer lo mismo, me ayudas por favor?

Comment: Esteban, utilice el código de la respuesta que marqué como correcta. Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contar días hábiles **Java**

Ejemplo que te regresa el numero de días hábiles laborables de lunes a viernes, no tomando en cuenta sábados, domingos y días festivos por ejemplo 1 de enero, 25 de diciembre los cuales agregaremos a una lista de fechas no laborables, y obtenemos las los días hábiles dado en un rango de fechas, fecha inicial y fecha final.

```
public int diasHabiles(Calendar fechaInicial, Calendar fechaFinal, List<Date> listaFechasNoLaborables) {
       int diffDays = 0;
       boolean diaHabil = false;
       //mientras la fecha inicial sea menor o igual que la fecha final se cuentan los dias
       while (fechaInicial.before(fechaFinal) || fechaInicial.equals(fechaFinal)) {

          if (!listaFechasNoLaborables.isEmpty()) {
              for (Date date : listaFechasNoLaborables) {
                  Date fechaNoLaborablecalendar = fechaInicial.getTime();
                  //si el dia de la semana de la fecha minima es diferente de sabado o domingo
                  if (fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY && fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && !fechaNoLaborablecalendar.equals(date)) {
                      //se aumentan los dias de diferencia entre min y max
                      diaHabil = true;
                  } else {
                      diaHabil = false;
                      break;
                  }
              }
          } else {
              if (fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY && fechaInicial.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY) {
                  //se aumentan los dias de diferencia entre min y max
                  diffDays++;
              }
          }
          if (diaHabil == true) {
          diffDays++;
          }
          //se suma 1 dia para hacer la validacion del siguiente dia.
          fechaInicial.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
     }
     return diffDays;
  }
```

[Ver aquí ejemplo completo](http://blog.softmolina.com.mx/wp/2016/12/22/contar-dias-habiles-en-java/)

Comment: Gracias, estoy implementando mi caso. EL único percance que tengo ahora, es que tengo que comparar el MM-dd o tendre que ingresar el mismo dia-mes para distintos años

Comment: Me anda bien, muchas gracias

Comment: Me da mucho gusto que te allá sido de utilidad saludos